# node.js defining same array for each room different

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, socket.io, node.js-domains

As I said at title, I want to define a different array for each room. For example:

For **room1**, array will be `var colors=['red','blue'],`

for **room2**, array will be `var colors=['black','white']`. (Same name but different content)

Here is my simplified server:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(3000).set('log level', 2);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var room = socket.handshake.query.room;  // room1 -- ws://localhost:3000/?room=room1

    socket.join(r); // add client to 'room1' room.
    // var colors = ['yellow','green'];
    io.sockets.in(r).emit('m', colors);
}
```

I don't want something like `if(h=='room1') { var colors=['a','b'];} elseif(room=='room2') { var colors=['y','z']; }` because
there will be a lot of rooms.

How can I achive this? Should I use namespaces instead of rooms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then have an object with room names as keys, with corresponding arrays. Then use the current room name to automatically get the color array from the color list:

```
var colorList = {
      'room1' : ['a','b'],
      'room2' : ['y','z']
    }
  , colors = colorList[room]
  ;
```